# Ktor Make Entity Column Not Nullable (match property type)

Tags: kotlin, entity, ktor

`MySQL` and `ktorm` dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.ktorm', name: 'ktorm-core', version: '3.4.1'
implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.25'
```

`Student` entity:

```
object StudentEntity : Table<Nothing>("student") {
    val id = int("id").primaryKey()        //<- non nullable type
    val name = varchar("name")
    val age = int("age")
    val gender = int("gender")
}
```

`get()` :

```
get("/students") {
    val students = database.from(StudentEntity).select().map {
        val id = it[StudentEntity.id]!!        //<- nullable
        val name = it[StudentEntity.name]!!
        val age = it[StudentEntity.age]!!
        val gender = it[StudentEntity.gender]!!

        Student(id, name, age, gender)
    }

    call.respond(students)
}
```

---

**Update on 12/12/2021:** [Not supported](https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues/354)

Comment: Do you use the Exposed framework? if yes, what version?

Comment: @Aleksei Tirman Please see the updated info.

Comment: I cannot find methods of the `QueryRowSer` that return not nullable type so I suggest asking your question here https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues.